# Multi Image Gallery 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-gallery, uipicker

How can we built more than one image gallery in an iPhone application? The requirement is I have a picker in my view it has seven selections, each selection has one image gallery, by selecting the picker a correspondent image gallery will apper in the view.

I am greatly appreciative of any guidance or help.

Comment: Please provide some more details on the components you are using, what picker for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple create a gallery controller pass an array of images when you tap on a picker row select array of images for that index and then push/present gallery controller on screen.